# Mysql query vtiger left join

Tags: mysql, vtiger

i want to make report with vtiger crm databases, This is so far i have tried mysql query like below:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(vtiger_crmentity.createdtime,'%d/%m/%Y') as "Tanggal Transaksi",DATE_FORMAT(due_date ,'%d/%m/%Y') as "Tanggal Jatuh Tempo",campaignname as "No. Kartu Kredit",contact_no as "Customer ID",concat(firstname," ", lastname) as "Nama",FORMAT(vtiger_servicecontractscf.cf_1107, 0, 'de_DE') as "Tagihan Bank",FORMAT(vtiger_servicecontractscf.cf_1095, 0, 'de_DE') as "Gesek",FORMAT(vtiger_servicecontractscf.cf_1101, 0, 'de_DE') as "Titip Bayar",if (cf_1101-accountingpaidamount>0,FORMAT(cf_1101-accountingpaidamount, 0, 'de_DE'),0) as "Hutang TB", if (cf_1101-accountingpaidamount>0,"Belum Lunas","Sudah Lunas") as "Status Lunas TB",vtiger_accounting.description as "Keterangan" 
FROM vtiger_servicecontracts, vtiger_crmentity, vtiger_servicecontractscf, vtiger_campaign, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_sqlreportscf, vtiger_sqlreports

LEFT JOIN vtiger_accounting
on vtiger_accounting.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
LEFT JOIN vtiger_accounting_payments
on vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction=vtiger_accounting.accountingid

WHERE vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and
vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155
and vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and vtiger_sqlreports.sqlreportsid=204
and vtiger_sqlreports.sqlreportsid=vtiger_sqlreportscf.sqlreportsid
AND (vtiger_crmentity.createdtime BETWEEN cf_1157 and cf_1159)

group by campaignname
```

My purpose:
i want to display query which has connection or does not have connection with  table vtiger_accounting and vtiger_accounting_payments.

the result query is:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid' in 'on clause'

what should I modify to accomplish with my purpose?

sorry for bad english

Thanks!

Comment: figure out what the real field name is?  obviously `servicecontractsid` doesn't exist in `vtiger_servicecontracts`.

Comment: Yup check to see if it is spelled correctly

Comment: i dont think i mispelled:

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vtiger_servicecontracts` (
  `servicecontractsid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,......
  `contactid` int(19) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: @DeviSiscaYulita Please paste the `desc vtiger_servicecontracts` here, In vtiger Database there should be `servicecontractsid` in vtiger_servicecontracts table, Otherwise Service Contract module wont work.